# Unable to find Ubuntu directory in order to delete it

Tags: find, locate

Hello all and sorry for the newbie question, but I'm going through this tutorial: [How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi/63613#63613) and am unable to find the Ubuntu subdirectory to delete it. I've been through several of the articles on here: [Using locate to find a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15184/using-locate-to-find-a-directory) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887522/how-to-search-for-a-directory-from-the-terminal-in-ubuntu etc. with no success. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you trying to remove the Ubuntu entry fro the EFI partition. Or do you think there is a directory called Ubuntu some place on your hard drive? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @David Thank you for response and sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to remove the Ubuntu entry from the EFI partition.

Comment: @David Looking at the article more closely I noticed it says "Now you should also delete the ubuntu subdirectory in the EFI partition to prevent the UEFI firmware from restoring the entry into the BootOrder." So I guess I'm trying to remove a subdirectory (directory??) called "Ubuntu" not to be confused with another? subdirectory? called "ubuntu." I know I sound lost - because I am. lol

Comment: Dawn, thank you for your help! the partition was located in /dev/sda1 so I did sudo mkdir /mnt/efipart
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/efipart
However when I try to cd/mnt/efipart I get a bash: cd: /mnt/efipart: Permission denied.

Comment: @Dawn I went through this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/998214/permission-denied-when-i-try-to-cd-into-any-folder and I'm going to do a fresh install. Just to be safe.

Comment: Welp. I tried. I changed the boot order to boot from USB (where the Ubuntu 22.04 image that I originally installed from) and now I'm getting stuck on the GRUB screen - again. Ready to throw in the bloody towel. Been days struggling with this. Maybe it's just time to admit defeat. ha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you successfully mounted the partition with the following command (assuming your EFI partition is located in `/dev/sda2`. If not, you need to replace `/dev/sda2` with the actual partition name to mount it to `/mnt/efipart`)

```bash
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/efipart
```

then, you can change directories to it and search:

```bash
cd /mnt/efipart
find . -name '*buntu'
```

If you use the wildcard `*`, then then it will match `Ubuntu` and `ubuntu`. If you do not have sufficient permissions to `cd` into `/mnt/efipart`, you can switch users with `sudo su` and you will now have root permission (`sudo` is no longer needed for each command). Be careful while you have root permission (and you will notice your prompt has changed to `#`). To return to your user permissions, simply enter `exit`

Comment: @jon, if your user id lacks permissions to `cd  /mnt/efipart`, you have 2 options: lower the permissions of `/mnt/efipart` (`sudo chmod 777 /mnt/efipart`) or elevate your permissions (`sudo su`).  Read my answer above about how using `sudo su` gives you root permissions.